# insert value in a list ignoring nan

Tags: python, list, numpy

How to insert a value right before the nan in a list having nan at the end of the list?

```
random = [9,1,5, ... 7,6,3,2,5, nan, nan, nan, ...]

random.append(8181) < somehow add function here
```

results should be, the value inserted before first nan

```
random = [9,1,5, ... 7,6,3,2,5,8181, nan, nan, nan, ...]
```

Comment: You can solve this with a combination of `list.index()` and `list.insert()`.

Comment: If amount of nan is static during loop execution, use insert with negative index.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I don't see any loop here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, you think he has few insertions written line by line?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice [`list.index` may not work correctly with nan](https://repl.it/@wimglenn/oh-nan-nan-nan-whats-my-name).

Comment: @wim TIL. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traverse the list from end to find the correct position, then use `list.insert`:

```
import math

i = 0
while math.isnan(random[i - 1]):
    i -= 1

random.insert(i, 8181)
```

Answer (score 1):

If we know how many `NaN` values we have then we can use `insert` with a negative count.

```
my_list.insert(-nan_count, 8181)
```

If we don't know the count, then we need to find out the last position.

```
for i,v in enumerate(reversed(my_list)): # loop backwards
    if v==v:
        a.insert(len(a)-i, 8181) # found the first non NaN, insert just before this
        break # only do it for the first item
```